# Spectrum Analyzer - Acquisition time computation

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

Using a spectrum analyzer, is there a theorical equation that links acquisition duration and acquisition parameters ( Span, RBW, VBW, sweep time and averages number )
Does this equation depends on the equipment or is a general rule?

Comment: well, have you looked at how such a classical analyzer works? It's really not hard – and it's easy for you to derive an answer if you just try to understand the things it does.

Comment: While all these parameters are theoretically related, I think you'll need to consult your user manual to get the specifics of your instrument.